# XCode Barcode Scanner Phonegap Auto Focus

Tags: ios, cordova, zxing, autofocus

I develop phonegap ios application.I used barcode scanner zxing library. But I have a problem
How to implement camera auto focus ?

thank you

My Code:

```
-(NSString*)setUpCaptureSession {
    NSError* error = nil;

    AVCaptureSession* captureSession = [[[AVCaptureSession alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.captureSession = captureSession;

    AVCaptureDevice* device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if (!device) return @"unable to obtain video capture device";

    AVCaptureDeviceInput* input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
    if (!input) return @"unable to obtain video capture device input";

    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput* output = [[[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init] autorelease];
    if (!output) return @"unable to obtain video capture output";

    NSDictionary* videoOutputSettings = [NSDictionary
                                         dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
                                         forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey
                                         ];


    output.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = YES;
    output.videoSettings = videoOutputSettings;

    [output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    if (![captureSession canSetSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium]) {
        return @"unable to preset medium quality video capture";
    }

    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

    if ([captureSession canAddInput:input]) {
        [captureSession addInput:input];
    }
    else {
        return @"unable to add video capture device input to session";
    }

    if ([captureSession canAddOutput:output]) {
        [captureSession addOutput:output];
    }
    else {
        return @"unable to add video capture output to session";
    }

    // setup capture preview layer
    self.previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:captureSession];

    // run on next event loop pass [captureSession startRunning]
    [captureSession performSelector:@selector(startRunning) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Which implementation of zxing are you using?  zxingObjC has a method on the capture object 'setFocusMode'

Comment: No, I using phonegap plugin.This Link:https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/tree/master/src/ios

setSession Code:

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it appears that the plugin you are using doesn't expose the capture device directly.  It does, however, expose the `AVCaptureSession` via the `captureSession` property.  From this property you should be able to work backwards to get the `AVCaptureInputDevice`

```
AVCaptureSession *session=[zxing captureSession];  //Assuming zxing the variable holding a reference to your zxing instance
NSArray *inputs= [session inputs];
AVCaptureInputDevice *input=(AVCaptureInputDevice *)inputs[0];   // Obtain first input device
AVCaptureDevice *device=input.device;

NSError *error;

if ([device lockForConfiguration:&error])
{
    device.focusMode=AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus;
   [device unlockForConfiguration];
}
else
{
  // TODO Handle the device lock error
}
```

Comment: Paul thank you.I am not objective c programmer.ı am beginner.
I checked my plugin code and setSession code block.
How to the implement your code ? I tryed but not changed.

I added my setSession code block

Comment: Ok, I am a little confused, because the code you have posted doesn't come from the module you linked to.  Regardless your variable `device` is the same as my variable `device` in the answer, so you can just add the code to set the autofocus mode exactly as I have it - the bit from `NSError *error` onwards

Comment: Paul,
I changed my code.ios 6 version is running but ios 7 is not auto focus.What is the problem ? your idea ? thank you

Comment: Does the camera you are using on your iOS 7 device support autofocus?  You can call `[device isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus]` to get a boolean indication

Comment: Paul , I testing my code. I found a bug. Problem is , dispatch_get_main_queue . This code is my camare preview do blur problem.Focus not working.But ı created new dispatch thread. Every things is ok but scan after is dont work. Why ?